# Html.ValidationMessageFor not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a MVC2 Project using ADO.NET Entity Data Model that I used to generate my view automatically since it has tons of fields.  It gave me code like this.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

<div class="editor-label">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Position) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Position) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Position) %>
</div>
```

But with a ton more fields.

Here is my Controller code:

```
MyProjectEntities_Career_Applications dbca = new MyProjectEntities_Career_Applications();

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Apply(Career_Applications application)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //save form
            dbca.AddToCareer_Applications(application);
            dbca.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Application could not be submitted.  Please correct the errors below.");
        }

        //redirect to thank you page
        return View("Apply", application);
    }
```

When the ModelState.IsValid fails I see the <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %> but none of the Html.ValidationMessageFor's ever show up.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the CSS.  Stupid mistake, ugh!

Thanks for the help regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a Jquery reference or error handling library that you're using.

This also happens often when you include validation script multiple times. (In shared view, and in your view)

Comment: Probably not since he did get his `ValidationSummary`

Comment: @Steve, he said that he is getting Validation summary after postback which means that server-side validation works. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I'll check into the jquery, I can't see anything apparent in the view source that suggests the errors are being placed with it though.  I am using the default MVC install so I don't think any libraries it isn't expecting are excluded.

Comment: my bad, I was thinking it showed before. It does show before as well when everything is wired.

Comment: Yes I do see the Validation Summary after post back.